# GREP in mutate function

Tags: r

I'm trying to re-class a dataset using GREP.  Id like to add a new column and populate it based on whether a string exists in another column:

```
wi.listings.Recode<-mutate(wi.listings, Check=ifelse(wi.listings$ListingDescription == grepl('Veranda', wi.listings$ListingDescription, ignore.case=TRUE), 'Veranda','Non Veranda'))
```

It returns all 'Non Veranda', so something is not working properly in the ifelse function.

Comment: You don't need to specify the object name $ within the `mutate`.  You are comparing `==` to a logical vector from `grepl`.  You need only `mutate(wi.listings, Check = ifelse(grepl("Veranda", ListingDescription, ignore.case = TRUE), "Veranda", "Non Veranda")))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is in the use of `==` to a `grepl` as `grepl` returns a logical vector.  We don't need to compare the original column with the logical vector again.  The `grepl` part would go into the `test` parameter of `ifelse`

```
mutate(wi.listings, Check = ifelse(grepl("Veranda", ListingDescription, 
              ignore.case = TRUE), "Veranda", "Non Veranda")))
```

Answer (score 0):

`grepl` returns a logical which you are then comparing to a character string (`ListingDescription`); this comparison will always return `FALSE`. Just use the result of grepl:

```
wi.listings.Recode <- mutate(wi.listings, HasVeranda = ifelse(grepl("Veranda", ListingDescription, ignore.case = TRUE), "Veranda", "Non Veranda"))
```

Additionally, you may be interested to learn about [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) which dplyr uses so that you don't have to explicitly reference column names from the data.frame being mutated.